# Detect bold texts in a cell and add ";" before those texts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, findandmodify

I have 3 columns that have the same pattern. Here is the example:

"
**I Love Chocolate**
I really love chocolate
I want to drink hot chocolate
**I have a red bike**
I buy it with my own money
**I hate mouse**
I hate mouse since I was little
"

I want to add semicolon before each of the line of bold texts in the cell. Like this:

"
;**I Love Chocolate**
I really love chocolate
I want to drink hot chocolate
;**I have a red bike**
I buy it with my own money
;**I hate mouse**
I hate mouse since I was little
"

I used a Macro like this, but it doesn't work. It gave no error warning; it just doesn't work as I wanted it to be.

```
Sub AddSemicolonBeforeBoldText()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim text As String
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim endPos As Integer
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            ' Skip cells with formulas
            GoTo ContinueLoop
        End If
        
        text = cell.Value
        startPos = 1
        
        Do While startPos <= Len(text)
            startPos = InStr(startPos, text, "*", vbTextCompare)
            If startPos = 0 Then Exit Do
            
            endPos = InStr(startPos + 1, text, "*", vbTextCompare)
            If endPos = 0 Then Exit Do
            
            ' Insert a semicolon before the bold text
            text = Left(text, startPos - 1) & ";" & Mid(text, startPos)
            startPos = endPos + 1 ' Move the start position after the second asterisk
        Loop
        
        cell.Value = text
        
        ContinueLoop:
    Next cell
End Sub
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are these seven lines in one cell or seven? Btw in a string asterisk doesn't mean bold.

Comment: @Blackcat this is all in one cell, ah I'm sorry, my bad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it steps backwards through each character in the cell, if the character is not bold and the character following it is bold then it adds a semicolon (the semicolon itself being bold)

```
Sub AddSemicolonBeforeBoldText()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            ' Skip cells with formulas
            GoTo ContinueLoop
        End If
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = cell.Characters.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
            If i = 0 Or Not cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold Then
                If cell.Characters(i + 1, 1).Font.Bold Then
                    cell.Characters(i + 1, 0).Insert ";"
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
ContinueLoop:
    Next cell
End Sub
```

... if you want, you can also tidy the code up further by eliminating the `GoTo` as follows

```
Sub AddSemicolonBeforeBoldText()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = cell.Characters.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
                If i = 0 Or Not cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold Then
                    If cell.Characters(i + 1, 1).Font.Bold Then
                        cell.Characters(i + 1, 0).Insert ";"
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**Answer updated with images**

The code will change this ...

[image: Original cell text]

... to this ...

[image: Updated cell text]

Comment: I think I misprased the question. What I want to achieve that I want to have a semicolon before the line of bold texts

Comment: That's exactly what it does, if I understand you correctly. So in the example you gave, the code will add a semicolon immediately before "I Love Chocolate", "I have a red bike" and "I hate mouse" ... if this isn't right then please clarify further ... perhaps you could add an image to the question of what the cell / text should look like after the code is run (ie with the semicolons)?

Comment: Yes you understood me very clearly, that is what I wanted. But after I tried the code, it only works on a cell that only has bold texts, and not a cell that has combination of bold text and regular texts

Comment: See images added to answer ... please check you are running the code I supplied, not the code supplied in the other answer?!

Comment: I tried it with a custom text and it worked. But for a Spreadsheet converted from PDF, it didn't work. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like an entirely new question to me ... respectfully suggest you mark this answer as accepted and ask a new question giving example(s) of the text produced in cells from the PDF

Comment: This is a very witty and resourceful solution, i vote it

Answer (score 1):

### Prepend String to Bold Cell Row

[image]

```vb
Sub PrependStringToBoldCellRow()
    
    Const INSERT_STRING As String = ";"
    Const PREVENT_CONSECUTIVE_INSERTIONS As Boolean = True
    Const MATCH_INSERT_STRING_CASE As Boolean = False
    Const CELL_ROW_DELIMITER As String = vbLf ' or vbCrLf?
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.UsedRange
    
    Dim iLen As Long: iLen = Len(INSERT_STRING)
    Dim iCompare As VbCompareMethod:
    
    If MATCH_INSERT_STRING_CASE Then
        iCompare = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        iCompare = vbTextCompare
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim cell As Range, chars As Characters
    Dim sRows() As String, sStarts() As Long, sLens() As Long
    Dim u As Long, UB As Long, sStart As Long, sLen As Long
    Dim CellString As String, RowString As String
    Dim IsCellStringValid As Boolean, IsConsecutive As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        
        ' Validate
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then ' has no formula
            If VarType(cell.Value) = vbString Then
                CellString = CStr(cell.Value)
                If Len(CellString) > 0 Then
                    IsCellStringValid = True
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ is blank."
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ has no string."
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ has a formula."
        End If
        
        If IsCellStringValid Then
            IsCellStringValid = False ' reset for the next cell
            Debug.Print "Processing cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """."
            
            sRows = Split(CellString, CELL_ROW_DELIMITER)
            UB = UBound(sRows)
            ReDim sStarts(0 To UB): ReDim sLens(0 To UB)
            sStart = 1
            
            For u = 0 To UB
                sLen = Len(sRows(u))
                sStarts(u) = sStart
                sLens(u) = sLen
                sStart = sStart + sLen + 1
            Next u
            
            For u = UB To 0 Step -1
                Set chars = cell.Characters(sStarts(u), sLens(u))
                RowString = chars.Text
                
                If PREVENT_CONSECUTIVE_INSERTIONS Then
                    If InStr(1, RowString, INSERT_STRING, iCompare) _
                            = 1 Then ' begins with
                        IsConsecutive = True
                    End If
                End If
                
                If IsConsecutive Then
                    IsConsecutive = False ' reset for the next row string
                    Debug.Print vbTab & RowString & " (is bold; " _
                        & "prevented consecutive insertion)"
                Else
                    If chars.Font.Bold Then
                        Debug.Print vbTab & RowString & " (is bold; " _
                            & "inserting...)"
                        chars.Insert INSERT_STRING & RowString
                    Else
                        Debug.Print vbTab & RowString & " (is not bold)"
                    End If
                End If
            Next u
        End If
    
    Next cell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Semicolons prepended.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**Log**

```
Processing cell "A1".
    I hated mice since I was little (is bold; inserting...)
    I hate mice (is not bold)
    I bought it with my own money (is not bold)
    I have a red bike (is bold; inserting...)
    I want to drink hot chocolate (is not bold)
    I really love chocolate (is not bold)
    I Love Chocolate (is bold; inserting...)
Cell "A2" has a formula.
Cell "A3" has no string.
Cell "A4" has no string.
Processing cell "A5".
    AAA (is not bold)
Processing cell "A6".
    AAA (is bold; inserting...)
Cell "A7" has no string.
Cell "A8" has no string.
Cell "A9" has no string.
Cell "A10" has no string.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddSemicolonToBoldText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim text As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet to work with
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    
    ' Set the range to loop through (Columns A, B, and C from A1 to C2000)
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C2000")
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Font.Bold Then ' Check if the cell value is bold and not blank
            ' Split the cell value by spaces to handle multiple bold words within the same cell
            Dim words() As String
            words = Split(cell.Value, " ")
            
            ' Add a semicolon before each bold word
            For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
                If cell.Characters(Start:=InStr(cell.Value, words(i)), Length:=Len(words(i))).Font.Bold Then
                    words(i) = ";" & words(i)
                End If
            Next i
            
            ' Join the modified words back into the cell
            cell.Value = Join(words, " ")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: hi! thank you, but it only worked on cells that have all texts in bold. Whereas my cell have bold texts and regular texts.